# Python: Using 'Null' for mysql.connector's port argument

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql database and I fetch it via a domain like `www.mydomain-database.com`. this domain is given by a company for accessing my database by phpmyadmin. When I browse this domain, it fetches phpmyadmin login page.

I try to connect to this database by the following code:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = "www.mydomain-database.com",
        user = "root",
        passwd = "**",
        database = "database",
        charset = 'utf8', use_unicode=True
    )
```

When I run this, I get the following exept:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'https://www.mydomain-database.com:3306' (-2 Name or service not known)
```

As you can see, connector adds port `3306` to my host; but the url with this port is not valid & it doesn't fetch the phpmyadmin!

So, for canceling that change, I added the `port = ""` as an argument for my connection but I got another error that mentioned the port must be integer!

Now the question is, how can I remove that port number when connector tries to connect the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply a port. By default MySQL uses port 3306. If your MySQL instance is using a different port, then you can specify that port in the settings.

Do you have access to the MySQL instance?
If so you can try and run:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

to get your port number.

However, your error message refers to server **https://**
that is not normal, there should not be any reference to https://

Can you check your code in your app and make sure that

```
        host = "www.mydomain-database.com"
```

and not

```
        host = "https://www.mydomain-database.com"
```